# Mimic static property in javascript classes

Tags: javascript, class, static, ecmascript-6

What is the best way to keep a property for a class in es6 that mimics a static property?

Is it safe to use a property created in prototype chain?

```js
class Employee {
  constructor(name, creator) {
    this.name = name;
    if(! (creator in Employee.prototype)){
       Employee.prototype[creator] = 0;
      }
    Employee.prototype[creator]++;
  }
  static count(creator) {
    return Employee.prototype[creator];
  }
}


var y = new Employee("Jack", "x");
var z = new Employee("John", "y");
var jh = new Employee("John", "y");

console.log(Employee.count('x'), Employee.count('y'));
```

Comment: What's the point? you can simply set count on Employee `Empliyee.count = 0;`

Comment: @Maxx Basically, I am just trying to understand static properties, but check the updated second example

Comment: You can do it but it's almost useless. Static properties is just properties on your class like this `Employee.count`. No more no less. What you do with your prototype is absolutly has no relation to static properties

Comment: So I can use `Employee[creator]` in above scenario?

Comment: For future reference, assuming your code works properly (which it does in this case), and you're looking for good standard practices, more efficient solutions, etc. questions of this format are better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safe? Yes. Messy? Yes. Better alternative? You bet.

You should move your counter logic out of your constructor to clean it up a little. Try something like this:

```
class Employee {
  static count(creator) {
    return Employee[creator] || 0;
  }

  static increment(creator) {
    Employee[creator] = Employee.count(creator) + 1;
  }

  constructor(name, creator) {
    this.name = name;
    Employee.increment(creator);
  }
}
```

Just mind not to use a creator name like `count`, `increment`, `constructor`, `prototype`, etc. or you could overwrite your class properties.